# sed: How to find whole word which contains special char "/"?

Tags: sed

I would like to search an exact word which contains the special char `/` like this word "/var/tmp".
I found some example how to search whole word like this `sed '/\b$word\b/g'`
But it works only on standard words, not contains meta.
Any idea please?

INPUT>

```
 word="/var/tmp"
  cat /etc/mtab | grep $word
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lvvar /tmp/var/tmp ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lv_var_tmp /var/tmp xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lv_var_tmp /tmp/var/tmp xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

OUTPUT is working only with exact example, but  not with universal variable $word

```
cat /etc/mtab | grep $word | sed '/\b\/var\/tmp\b/g'
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lv_var_tmp /var/tmp xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

Not working output with variable, filter not working here

```
cat /etc/mtab | grep $word | sed '/\b\$word\b/g'
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lvvar /tmp/var/tmp ext4 rw,seclabel,relatime 0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lv_var_tmp /var/tmp xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
/dev/mapper/vgroot-lv_var_tmp /tmp/var/tmp xfs rw,seclabel,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

Comment: You can't `sed '/\b\$word\b/g'` because the single quotes keep the variable expansion from working - and even if you used double quotes it still won't work because you are escaping the dollar sign.  Also, if `$word` is going to contain `/` then you should use a different delimiter for sed.  Something like `sed "#\b\$word\b#g"`  You might also want to use double quotes around the parameter to grep - it works now but what if `$word` contained a semicolon, space, ampersand or some other character special to the shell?

Comment: I rolled back your new question. Accept the answer you got and ask a new question if you can't figure it out; but really, search before asking - these are common beginner questions.

Comment: Tangentially, avoid the [useless `cat`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)

Comment: @andrew: I think that you should explain to us what you understand by "word with metacharacters"? Which characters are allowed to be a part of the word? Which characters are the delimiters of the word? Etc...

Comment: Sorry for misunderstandings, I was meaning special character "/". Delimiuter is space.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` with a different delimiter for it. To use it in `address` position you need to escape the very first one - `\%`.

Also, as your word can start(and probable end) with `/`(non word character) you need to handle the beginning of words manually, not with `\b`. Otherwise you will not have a match.

Below is a working example:

```
$  cat txt
 asd fasd /asd fas
asd asd /asd/tmp/ asdf
/asd/tmp/ asdf
asdf
sadf asd asd/tmp

$  echo $word
/asd/tmp/

$  sed -nE "\%(^|\s)$word(\s|$)%p" txt
asd asd /asd/tmp/ asdf
/asd/tmp/ asdf
```

`-n` - tells sed do not print all lines
`-E` - to work with extended regexp syntax
`\%` - delimiter which shouldn't appear in `$word`
`(^|\s)` - match the very beginning of a line or space
`(\s|$)` - match a space or the end of line
`p` - tells sed to print matched lines